# Getting UnknownPluginException for com.android.dynamic-feature

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dynamic-feature

I'm trying to create a dynamic feature module and these dependencies got added by itself.
But when it try to sync gradle i'm getting this exception:

```
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.dynamic-feature', version: '8.1.2'] was not found in any
of the following sources
```

My gradle version is: `8.4`
and android gradle plugin version is: `8.1.2`

I'm not sure if `dynamic-feature` plugins are deprecated on these versions, can someone please share how to proceed here.

Thanks